# Data type when reading from a TSV-file (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im reading data from a tsv-file to a postgresql table. The problem I have is that in one column (death year) it is either a year or \N if the actor is not dead yet. If i try to use INTEGER as data type I get an error because of the \N. Do anyone know how to solve this?

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE name_mock(nconst VARCHAR, primaryName VARCHAR, birthYear INTEGER, deathYear INTEGER, primaryProfession VARCHAR, knownForTitles VARCHAR);
```

Then I import the data from the csv-file:

```
COPY name_mock FROM '/home/pathtofile/name.basics.tsv' DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER;
```

And I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "\N"
CONTEXT:  COPY name_mock, line 4, column deathyear: "\N"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the SQL statement you are using as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) -  [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please

Comment: Sorry for that, I've added what I've done now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COPY` takes a parameter, `NULL`.

Please try this:

```
COPY name_mock FROM '/home/pathtofile/name.basics.tsv' DELIMITER E'\t' NULL '\N' CSV HEADER;
```